# @Cacheable Annotation gives 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, redis

I have to implement Redis for cache management. I am following [this](https://medium.com/@MatthewFTech/spring-boot-cache-with-redis-56026f7da83a)
tutorial but the problem is when I use @Cacheable annotation on my controller method it gives me a 404 status code.

My Controller Method is as follows:

```
@GetMapping("auth/cache/{id}")
@Cacheable("test")
public ServiceResponse<String> checkingCache(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){
    return new ServiceResponse<>(new String("String with id "+id));
}
```

When I remove the cacheable annotation the method works as expected.

I have installed redis on my machine and it is running on default port. Redis configuration is as follows:

```
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
```

Is there something I am missing? Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have you enabled caching with annotation `@EnableCaching` described in your tutorial.

Also, because you need to cache for a specific id, you have to provide that key to che cache. Your example should be:

```
@GetMapping("auth/cache/{id}")
@Cacheable(value = "test", key = "#id")
public ServiceResponse<String> checkingCache(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){
    return new ServiceResponse<>(new String("String with id "+id));
}
```

If you have no `@PathVariable` you can annotate `@Cachable` without a key